# Draw and manipulate shapes through jquery ui or other alternatives

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this assignment where i need to create square and circle shapes and be able to manipulate their behaviour like being able to drag the shapes on top of each other. I've been looking into using jquery ui but i'm unable to find all the necesarry functionality. I know how to drag elements and im able to draw the elements using css or some js library but im unable to find documention regarding being able to move shapes on top of each other, i assume i need to use some sort of coordinates system but im no coding guru. Does jquery ui support this type of functionality? If not is there any alternatives i can use for the above mentioned functionality?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can make use of `draggable` and `resizable` features to manipulate elements. So the answer to your questions would simply be "Yes". Maybe you want to rephrase it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although your answer does not address my problem directly, i managed to identify the droppable method within jquery ui and that works for my purpose. Thank you again.

Comment: Did I misread your question? *Does jquery ui support this type of functionality?* Yes, it does.